# Windows PowerShell keeps autocompleting with the SendTo folder in the home directory

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, autocomplete

I'm using PowerShell on Windows 10. When I type `ls` in my home folder, the only folder that starts with an `s` is a folder called `source`. When I type `cd s` and then press the tab key, PowerShell autocompletes this to `cd .\SendTo\` despite the fact that this folder does not exist. If I try to `ls` in this folder, both as a regular user and administrator, it says `ls : Access to the path 'C:\Users\afranke\SendTo' is denied.` The same thing happens with `rm`.

What is this folder? Is it different from the SendTo folder in AppData? Is there a way that I can make this folder go away so that I can have autocomplete work with my `source` folder?

Comment: Some additional information: SendTo is a hidden folder inside `$env:userprofile`/`%userprofile%`. You can see it when you execute `ls -force`. I can't find any information to why it's there though after a quick google. in WinXP, this was the default location for the SendTo folder, before it was moved to AppData in Win7

Comment: It's there because it used to be there. If a program prior to WinXP tries to access something there it will work. It is a reparse point to read/write to files will work but affect the new location. It has a Deny for File Listing for Everyone so you don't get confused by it. It is also hidden.  All the older Win 95/ Win NT special folders have something like this. Setup programs will work EG in a command prompt `Type C:\windows\win.ini > "%userprofile%\SendTo\test.txt` and the file will end up `C:\Users\Your name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`

Comment: Press the tab key twice.